# How to get one value from json_encode php to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to get one by one of array `json_encode` to jquery but it's always getting error *undefined* and no one work, any suggestion to my code

```php
$response = array(
'antrian' => true,
'message' => 'Success print recipt'
);

echo json_encode($response);
```

```
$.ajax({
 url: urlPrintQueue,
 method: "POST",
 data: {id: id},
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(result)  {
  console.log(result[0]); // antrian
  console.log(result[1]);  // message 
 }
});
```

for *"antrian"* and *"message"* value i'm expect get the output but what i get is *undefined*

Comment: Print what contains in `result`.

Comment: result will be an object in js, so access like `console.log(result.message)`

Comment: yeah sure. but i want it one by one not all of result

Comment: np, if you want `result[0]` convention, do `result = Object.values(result)` or just return an array from php `json_encode([true, 'Success print recipt'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running an associative array through `json_encode()`.

If you passed a standard numeric array to `json_encode()`, your `result` in JS would be an array. When you pass an associative array however, `result` is going to be an object instead.

Instead of:

```
success: function(result)  {
  console.log(result[0]); // antrian
  console.log(result[1]);  // message 
}
```

You need to use:

```
success: function(result)  {
  console.log(result.antrian); // antrian
  console.log(result.message);  // message 
}
```

Comment: yeah sure has been answered by lawrence, but many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
// Pase if not json ajax request
var json = JSON.parse(result);

// Like this
console.log(json.message + ' ' + json.antrin );

// Or loop
for (var i in json.list){
    console.log( json.list[i].message + ' ' + json.list[i].antrian );
}
```

Regards